# What is better to fed into ANN for OCR: character's border or character's 'filling'?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ocr, neural-network

I am having hard time deciding what is better (in terms of performance) to fed into ANN for OCR purposes. I have found rectangular areas which contain characters and now I would like to know what is better to use :

- charater's border

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

- character's filling

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1 0

0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

I am asking before doing the testing mydelf because preparation of samples will take me a lot of time.
Sorry for formatting but I couldn't set the proper code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have a hard time figuring out what the optimal method is before you actually try because you are not going to be able to predict if your method is even going to give you a decent result anyway even if it meant less input data.

This is a classical problem that has been discussed in classic texts, there is an example here in Java:
http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/7
You haven't explained the structure of your intended ANN, this can be implemented in so many ways that you need to decide and explain what type of ANN you intend to use. You could use Auto-associator networks, NN with hidden layer with back propagation, etc..

Comment: Vary good article. I am using indeed ANN with one hidden layer and back propagation.

Comment: Well your first issue will be to determine what features/patterns to measure and how these map to the number of nodes in your hidden layer. Then you need to determine the activation function, whether you need to normalise the input and output values, how to measure your error, training data, improve training speed and generalisation. The article at least gives you some code to solidify against the theory, I would also look at the matlab neural network toolbox articles: [matlab](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/nnet/)